# Variance of number of matchs in a deck of card

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

Consider we have a shuffled deck of $n$ cards numbered $1 , . . . , n$. We say we have a **match** if card number $i$ be in position $i$ . example in sequence $1,4,3,2,5$ we have $3$ matches. Suppose $X$ be a random variable indicating number of matches in a deck of $n$ cards. How to calculate $Var(X)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $I_i$ be the indicator random variable for the event "card $i$ is in position $i$." (That is, $I_i = 1$ if the event holds, and $I_i=0$ otherwise.) Then $X = I_1 + \cdots + I_n$. Then,
$$\text{Var}(I_1 + \cdots + I_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(I_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \ne i} \text{Cov}(I_i, I_j),$$
and compute each term separately.
If you don't want to use this formula (don't know what covariance is, etc.), instead do $\text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ and compute $E[(I_1 + \cdots + I_n)^2]$ and $(E[I_1 + \cdots + I_n])^2$ by expanding.

Comment: is $E[(I_1 + ... + I_n)^2]$ equal to 
$E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}I_i I_j]$ ?

Comment: Yes, @mike . More precisely: $$\mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n I_i\right)^2\right)=\mathsf E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n I_i^2+2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^nI_iI_j\right)$$